# Deploying azure bot on website with directline 3.0 on NODEjs

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to host my web app on localhost. I am using directline 3.0 and I want to push the messages into a window using websockets. I don't want to embed the bot. I already have the GET and POST request so I can send and receive the conversation by running the javascript files with the bearer tokens and get back the conversation running by sending and receiving messages from the bot but I want this to take place on the localhost website on a chat based window without embedding.

How can I do this? How do I link the chat window of websockets to the GET and post files so i can send the messages in real time.

Comment: What do you mean by a chat based window? Are you looking for some sort of pop up chat that is initiated from the main localhost website? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you integrate Direct Line directly (no pun intended) into you project by using the [BotFramework-DirectLineJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) package. This package is built specifically for communicating with a bot without using WebChat as the UI component.

There is a v3 [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/Node/core-DirectLineWebSockets) that you can reference. The project splits between the DirectLineBot and the DirectLineClient. The DirectLineBot demonstrates a v3 bot. You'll need to update this folder to include your v4 bot. The DirectLineClient works the same with v3 or v4. So, as your client connects, generates a token, and begins sending activities, your v4 bot should pick these up and respond accordingly. Similarly, your client should pick up the bot's responses.

At this point, you need to update your client to display the activities as they are sent and received from the user / bot.

You might also consider looking over this unofficial "plain ui" [sample](https://github.com/compulim/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/sample-plain-ui) from the WebChat dev. It uses React however it does not rely on WebChat as the UI component. I was able to spin it up in about 5 mins. It is purposefully stripped of any styling and simply posts activities to the page as text/json objects.

You could remove the input field and configure the page to accept inputs to render on the page. It might be a useful starting place and could fit well with the above DirectLineJS option.

[image]

If none of those options are agreeable, then you will need to use Axios, Fetch, or some similar package to make your GET, POST, etc., calls between your client and bot.

Hope of help!